# How to run an SAP transaction with SAP closed or open or not logged in

Tags: vba, sap-gui

What I am trying to do is fairly simple:
I have a script which run transactions and I want the macro to always execute the transaction.

There are three cases:

1. SAP is NOT open (which the code works with, the first part is launching)
2. SAP is open AND logged in (the code also works)
3. SAP is open but NOT logged in (this is where the code fails)

This is the error:

> run-time error 614. 'The enumerator of the collection cannot find an element with the specified index'

(FYI, for the purposes here, I assume there is no password to login, so you just need to press enter)

```vb
'Launching SAP and logging into the main screen if the program is not already open
If IsProcessRunning("saplogon.EXE") = False Then
    Dim SapGui, Applic, connection, session, WSHShell
    
    Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe", vbNormalFocus
    Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    
    Do Until WSHShell.AppActivate("SAP Logon ")
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
    Loop
    
    Set WSHShell = Nothing
    Set SapGui = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set Applic = SapGui.GetScriptingEngine
    Set connection = Applic.OpenConnection("InsertTextHere", True)
    Set session = connection.Children(0)
    session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
End If
    
'Executing main screen, this part here is just setting variables for the logged in interface. So once this is done you can enter the transaction. 
    
If Not IsObject(XXX) Then
    Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set XXX = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
    Set connection = XXX.Children(0)
End If

'The error is here, when it tries to make session into connection.Children
If Not IsObject(session) Then
    Set session = connection.Children(0)

End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
    WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
    WScript.ConnectObject XXX, "on"
End If

'Transaction comes here

Function IsProcessRunning(process As String)
    Dim objList As Object
    
    Set objList = GetObject("winmgmts:") _
        .ExecQuery("select * from win32_process where name='" & process & "'")
    
    IsProcessRunning = objList.Count > 0
    
End Function
```

Edit: A little more context may be helpful. I made a macro that was supposed to save people time by auto accessing transactions, I added the instructions "You must already be logged into SAP before running it". Unfortunately, even if I put the text in bright red letters next to the button, I get a few emails a week informing me that there is an error, and every time it's somebody who didn't open SAP or somebody who isn't logged in.

Comment: Could you describe how your code fails, what symptom, what line of code, what you expect, etc.?

Comment: @SandraRossi Hi, the error I get is run-time error 614. 'The enumerator of the collection cannot find an element with the specified index'. Recall that this is the case where SAP is open but no login is done. So it skips the first section, then goes directly to the second, but cannot find transaction input.

Comment: Please clarify by editing the question also. Which line has the error? What if you start manually SAP Logon and you run a script which start from the line `If Not IsObject(XXX) Then`?

Comment: Note that you must make sure that SAP GUI software is installed with the SAP GUI Scripting component.

Comment: @SandraRossi Added a comment in the code to show where the error is. The code works when SAP is closed or logged in, which means that whatever software I need must already be available. I think that the solution should be something like:
1) If closed DO XYZ,
2) If open but not logged in, DO YZ,
3) If Open and logged in DO Z. 

But I am not sure how to create the second condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The topic is apparently still of interest. The version with SingleSignOn in particular has the 3 states described by Exxonboy. Missing state number 2 could be recognized as follows.

for example:

```
'Launching SAP and logging into the main screen if the program is not already open

If IsProcessRunning("saplogon.EXE") = False Then
Dim SapGui, Applic, connection, session, WSHShell

Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe", vbNormalFocus

Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do Until WSHShell.AppActivate("SAP Logon ")
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
Loop

Set WSHShell = Nothing
Set SapGui = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set Applic = SapGui.GetScriptingEngine
Set connection = Applic.OpenConnection("InsertTextHere", True)
Set session = connection.Children(0)
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
End If

'Executing main screen, this part here is just setting variables for the  logged in interface. So once this is done you can enter the transaction. 

'-----------new--------------------------
on error resume next
'-----------new--------------------------
If Not IsObject(XXX) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set XXX = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
   '-----------new--------------------------
   myError = err.number
   '-----------new--------------------------
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = XXX.Children(0)
   '-----------new--------------------------
   myError = err.number
   '-----------new--------------------------
End If

If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session = connection.Children(0)
   '-----------new--------------------------
   myError = err.number
   '-----------new--------------------------
End If
'-----------new--------------------------
on error goto 0
If myError <> 0 Then
  Set connection = XXX.OpenConnection("InsertTextHere", True)
  Set session = connection.Children(0)
  session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
End If
'-----------new--------------------------

If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject XXX, "on"
End If

'Transaction comes here

Function IsProcessRunning(process As String)
Dim objList As Object

Set objList = GetObject("winmgmts:") _
    .ExecQuery("select * from win32_process where name='" & process & "'")

IsProcessRunning = objList.Count > 0

End Function
```

Regards, ScriptMan

Comment: Hi. Trying to figure out where your code goes.

Is it after the first if loop? or you expect this to replace the bottom section?

Comment: The 2nd variant with replace the bottom section is correct.

Comment: It's just a pity that we don't know if it worked now.

Comment: problem is that I am not sure what you code does

I found another workaround in the meantime which just involves me moving everything after the while loop, to be outside of the if loop. if you can explain what the code does I can confirm deny it works :)

Comment: I just expanded your program. The extensions are marked. An explanation of this is as follows:
If saplogon.exe is active but the user is not logged in, an error occurs. Then you know that you have to log in first.

Comment: Works! Sorry for the delay. Busy week :)