# Open SAP from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, office365, sap-gui

I have the same error as [How to run an SAP transaction with SAP closed or open or not logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70929690/how-to-run-an-sap-transaction-with-sap-closed-or-open-or-not-logged-in).
SAP-Logon and SAP are openend and then comes the error.

> run-time error 614. 'The enumerator of the collection cannot find an
> element with the specified index'

Already tried code from ScriptMan but no luck.

Error always comes on line:

```
Set Session = Connection.Children(0)
```

My SAP-Version with Single Sign On:

```
SAP Logon für Windows
760 Final Release
7600.1.6.1160
1998402
```

<< Edit >>

Here is my code:

```vb
Sub test()
'Launching SAP and logging into the main screen if the program is not already open

If IsProcessRunning("saplogon.exe") = False Then
Dim SapGui, Applic, connection, session, WSHShell, myError, WScript

Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SapGui\saplogon.exe", vbNormalFocus

Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do Until WSHShell.AppActivate("SAP Logon ")
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
Loop

Set WSHShell = Nothing
Set SapGui = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set Applic = SapGui.GetScriptingEngine
Set connection = Applic.OpenConnection("050 LYB PRD - SAP Production", True)
'error comes here if SAP-Logon and SAP is not logged in
Set session = connection.Children(0)
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
End If

'Executing main screen, this part here is just setting variables for the  logged in interface. So once this is done you can enter the transaction.

'-----------new--------------------------
On Error Resume Next
'-----------new--------------------------
If Not IsObject(XXX) Then
   Set SapGui = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set XXX = SapGui.GetScriptingEngine
   '-----------new--------------------------
   myError = Err.Number
   '-----------new--------------------------
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = XXX.Children(0)
   '-----------new--------------------------
   myError = Err.Number
   '-----------new--------------------------
End If

If Not IsObject(session) Then
'error comes here if SAP-Logon is open and SAP is connected
   Set session = connection.Children(0)
   '-----------new--------------------------
   myError = Err.Number
   '-----------new--------------------------
End If
'-----------new--------------------------
On Error GoTo 0
If myError <> 0 Then
  Set connection = XXX.OpenConnection("050 LYB PRD - SAP Production", True)
'error comes here if only SAP-Logon is open and SAP not connected
  Set session = connection.Children(0)
  session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
End If
'-----------new--------------------------

If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject Applic, "on"
End If

'Transaction comes here
End Sub

Function IsProcessRunning(process As String)
Dim objList As Object

Set objList = GetObject("winmgmts:") _
    .ExecQuery("select * from win32_process where name='" & process & "'")

IsProcessRunning = objList.Count > 0

End Function
```

Comment: It just means that ther is no sap session with the index 0. Have you started the SAPLOGON Pad? Have you connected to a SAP system?

Comment: Yes the macro opens SAP-Logon and connects to the right system, but no sessions where found. The connection.count is 0 when the error comes.

Comment: I'd suggest that you edit your post and show more of your code.

Comment: This is the full macro i have.

Comment: I can only re-produce the error in case SAPLOGON Pad is started and I haven't logged on to any system. So, are you sure that you have logged on to SAP?

Comment: In this case the macro should connect to the system.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: If myError <> 0 Then
  Set connection = XXX.OpenConnection("050 LYB PRD - SAP Production", True)
  Set session = connection.Children(0)
  session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
End If

Comment: I edited the code with comments to show where the errors come.

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot reproduce the error.